# Azure AD access token from postman

Tags: azure, postman, authorization

Today, I have an issue getting an Azure AD access token from Postman. This is while it was working before for the same app and other apps I am working on. But none of them are working today.
I was working correctly, but now it shows me this error:

*Error: AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'*

I use https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize as auth URL, and https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/token for Access token URL.
I have tried these for access token URL but none of them worked. [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7Btenant_id%7D%7D/v2.0/token)
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/token
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/token)
here is my Azure AD oauth 2.0 configuration. Also, as you see, there is no client_id in the request body.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if your client_id, and other `variables` are defined and enabled, see this postman [help](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#fixing-unresolved-variables) for more details.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran They are defined and enabled, the issue is that even the previouse apps I have in my postman collection has the same error. I was using them without issue, but now all the requests has error. Is anything changed in postman or Azure AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it's acting like this:
I checked my friend's PC, and it was working there!
The issue was the last update of Postman. They have changed something in authorization.
just change the **Client Authentication** to **Send client credentials in body** and it will work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***

You can get **values** of auth URL and access token URL from your Azure AD application that varies based on **supported account type** like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Your App -> Overview -> Endpoints*

[image]

Now I added **environment variables** in Postman by defining them like below:

[image]

Make sure to select the correct **Environment** while requesting for token with `variables`.

I filled the **required details** same as you to get the access token like below:

[image]

When I selected **Get New Access Token**, I got the `token` successfully as below:

[image]

> The error usually occurs if you missed including `client_id` while
> acquiring access token.

I changed  `client_id` parameter to **blank** in variables like below:

[image]

When I tried to get access token again, I got **same error** as you like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to pass `client_id` value in right environment and **save** it.